# Probability of Failure in System

Tags: probability

I was a given a question and its supposed solution, but I'm getting to a different result in the end. Please let me know if my reasoning is correct.

> Consider the following system. The failure probability of each
>   component is mentioned on the figure and we assume that the failures
>   of the components are independent of each other.

[image]

> Assume that the failure probability of component A is equal to $x$.
>   What is then the failure probability of the system (as a function of
>   $x$)?

I reasoned it's easier to think of the probability of failure as $1 - P\left( W \right)$, where $P(W)$ is the probability that it works flawlessly.
So, since in order for the system to work, each of the components must work,
$$\eqalign{
  & 1 - P\left( W \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( F \right) = 1 - P\left( W \right) = 1 - \left( {1 - 0.25} \right)\left( {1 - 0.1} \right)\left( {1 - 0.3} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( F \right) = 1 - \left( {0.75} \right)\left( {0.9} \right)\left( {0.7} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)  \cr 
  & P\left( F \right) = 0.5275 + 0.4725x \cr} $$

While the solution shows
[image]

I experimented multiplying it to open the expression and it seems indeed a different one.

Comment: The system will work if *at least on one* of the $3$ routes there is/are no failures. So not necessarily all routes. You better do not go for $1-P(W)$ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption that all of them need to work was the problem; it turns out it's not a condition for the system to work.